# Is it possible to save a link in table in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a page with many links on a sidebar (about 20), but the code looks bad with this approach. Is it possible to save all `<a href=....` in a table, an array or something?

Can anybody help me out with an example?

After clicking on the sidebar, the links should be loaded into the page. Do I have to save the link and the script (maybe?) in the table ?

**The HTML-markup to save:**

```
<li>
   <a href="clients.html" id="ex">Clients</a>
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ex").click(function(event){
            $("#content").load('example.html');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't know what you are trying to achieve. do you want to save the links at runtime - or do you want to save them to a database?

Comment: boss told me to save all links in table because now i have 20 times <li><a href=.. so for him is unreadable ;/ and i dont know how write it.

Comment: in a html table? like `<table><tr><td><a href=..></td></tr><tr><td><a href=..></td></tr></table>` ?

Comment: How php is related to this?

Comment: no, i thinking about array in php.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for something like this:

```
$linklist = array();
$linklist[] = array('file' => 'clients.html', 'id' => 'ex', 'linktext' => 'Clients');
$linklist[] = array('file' => 'somefile.html', 'id' => 'someID', 'linktext' => 'someText');
```

then you can create your list like this:

```
foreach($linklist AS $link) {
    print "<a href='" . $link['file']."' id='".$link['id'].">".$link['linktext']."</a>";
}
```

Comment: Your solution is very good, I prefer it as a better one as mine(visibility - what the OP wants and functionality - multiarray).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to is to save all of them directly in a PHP array.

```
<?php
$list = array(
"<li><a href="clients.html" id="ex">Clients</a></li>",
"<li><a href="main.html" id="main">Main</a></li>",
"<li><a href="another.html" id="an">Another</a></li>",
"<li><a href="test.html" id="test">Test</a></li>"
);
?>
```

And echo them whenever you want using foreach (or using for loop):

```
foreach ($list as $val) {
echo $val;
}
```

Now it depends how your clients.html (and others) are built. If they accept PHP, you can save the php code to a new file (i.E. **menu.php**).

So that you'll have all data in one file (so you don't need to change it 20 times manually), all you have to do is include it into the files. So it will look like:

```
<?php include_once("menu.php"); ?>
```

Comment: is not exactly what i try to do but is very helpful :) thanks.

Comment: one more question, do you know how run my script with array of links. how get id from array?

Comment: @pbwned, the information in this is slightly misleading (not in a terrible way), you need to escape the double quotation marks in each item in the array to avoid an error. For example, `"<li><a href="clients.html" id="ex">Clients</a></li>",` SHOULD be `"<li><a href=\"clients.html\" id=\"ex\">Clients</a></li>",` OR `'<li><a href="clients.html" id="ex">Clients</a></li>',` (the latter of the two is tidier)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 download attribute like so

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to save</a>
```

This opens a "save as" dialog regardless of file type without taking you away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer given by @pbwned, you would have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    "<li><a href=\"clients.html\" id=\"list_item_%s\">Clients</a></li>",
    "<li><a href=\"main.html\" id=\"list_item_%s\">Main</a></li>",
    "<li><a href=\"another.html\" id=\"list_item_%s\">Another</a></li>",
    "<li><a href=\"test.html\" id=\"list_item_%s\">Test</a></li>"
    );

$id = 1;
foreach ($list as $val) {
    echo sprintf($val, $id);
    ++$id;
}
?>

<script>
    var count_list_item = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li").each(function () {
            ++count_list_item;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < count_list_item; ++i) {
            $("#list_item_" + i).on('click', function (event) {
                    $("#content").load($("#list_item_" + i).attr("href"));
                    return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will not be perfect, but its something and I hope it helps you.